# Is Doc Green the Hulk with Bruce Banner’s mind? If so, how did that happen?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

I read some comics where Hulk is Doc Green, and he's a genius. So, I think that's Banner's mind in the Hulk.

Am I right? If that's true, how did that happen?

Comment: There is also The Professor.

Comment: @cde and The Maestro

Answer (score 12):

#### No, [Doc Green](http://www.comicvine.com/hulk/4005-2267/)  identifies himself as neither the Hulk nor Banner, but as a different entity entirely:

The Doc Green persona emerged after an assassination attempt on Bruce Banner:

> After Banner was repeatedly shot in the back of the skull by a then unknown assassin, his brain was subjected to Arno Stark's Extremis Virus. **It was then that a new Hulk persona emerged in the form of Doc Green: The Smartest & Strongest One There is. This particular incarnation of the Hulk neither recognizes himself as either Dr. Bruce Banner or any of the various Hulk personas/incarnations**. He has thus made it his mission to eliminate all gamma-based weapons and threats from the planet. This includes the other Hulks: Skaar, Red She-Hulk, Lyra, She-Hulk, A-Bomb and Red Hulk.

Comment: Shouldn't have clicked on that link. There goes my day...